# Crash Log - SIGTRAP - iPhone Simulator Using XCode 4.2

Tags: crash, ios-simulator, xcode4.2, crash-reports

I have this crash issue after I upgrade using XCode 4.2. It never happened when I use 4.0.2 before. The strangest thing is that it happened intermittently, as it sometime happened and sometime it didn't. Please help me figuring out what the cause of the crash from the log below :

```
Interval Since Last Report:          627313 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           59
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   14
Anonymous UUID:                      FF7C9791-6E3A-4A0C-AB83-35DE0C08166B

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
iPhone Simulator 272, iPhone OS 4.3.2 (iPhone/8H7)
iPhone Simulator 272, iPhone OS 4.3.2 (iPhone/8H7)


Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9639baa2 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x963c79c5 nanosleep$UNIX2003 + 188
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x963c7903 usleep$UNIX2003 + 61
3   QuartzCore                      0x0168549d CABackingStoreCollectBlocking + 209
4   UIKit                           0x00f27e98 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 1719
5   UIKit                           0x00f31039 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 4127
6   UIKit                           0x00f28abf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
7   UIKit                           0x00f2df2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
8   GraphicsServices                0x027f5992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
9   CoreFoundation                  0x01b9f944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
10  CoreFoundation                  0x01affcf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
11  CoreFoundation                  0x01afcf83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
12  CoreFoundation                  0x01afc840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
13  CoreFoundation                  0x01afc761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
14  GraphicsServices                0x027f41c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
15  GraphicsServices                0x027f4289 GSEventRun + 115
16  UIKit                           0x00f31c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
17  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX                  0x00184f69 main + 121 (main.m:14)
18  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX                  0x00002af5 start + 53
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's always these little problems in certain projects whenever xcode updates. There may be a solution to this problem that doesn't involve my solution, so I would wait for other answers before using mine.

I would always just copy/paste all of my important code, organized in text documents so that I can tell what everything used to be, then I would Un-Install (after uninstalling, delete every subfolder and all leftovers of the previous version. All projects and classes) then Re-install, create new projects and copy/paste your old code. This SHOULD fix the problem, but as I said this is a hassle so see if anyone else cam come with a more specific answer to your problem.